# Is it possible and if ok, then how to transform data inside ngrx effect?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

```
//app.effect.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import {addCityToIndex, returnCityToIndex} from './reducers/form.reducer';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpService } from './services/http.service';

@Injectable()
export class AppEffects {

  effect$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(addCityToIndex),
      map(data => returnCityToIndex(data))
    ), {});

  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private http: HttpService) {}
}
```

I need to update data, which I have in addCityToIndex (array) via http service - get property of array element, make request to service, update element and pass new array to returnCityToIndex.

Is it possible and if ok, then how to transform data inside ngrx effect?

Comment: I think the recommended way is to return a new action, something like `addCityToIndexSuccess`. Then create a reducer that listens transforms the data when that action is dispatched. The effect will dispatch the returned action.

Comment: I return new action returnCityToIndex and I have reducer for it. Did I right undestand, that you wrote?

Comment: Yes, if `returnCityToIndex(data)` creates an action, and you have have a reducer for that action type, it should work. If it doesn't work, please share the code for `addCityToIndex` and `returnCityToIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [documentation](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/operators)

You can use a `action` to trigger a request and return another `action` witch will update your state, and your component will recive the new data in `selector` when the data be updated.

Ex:

```js
  login$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(LoginPageActions.login),
      exhaustMap(action =>
        this.authService.login(action.credentials).pipe(
          map(user => AuthApiActions.loginSuccess({ user })),
          catchError(error => of(AuthApiActions.loginFailure({ error })))
        )
      )
    )
  );
```